# Unable to download "firebase/init.json" for self-hosting the sign-in helper code

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase authentication for one of my applications and want to implement `signInWithRedirect` (instead of `signInWithPopup`). I am following the documentation provided [`here`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices) and want to host the files locally (option 4).

Based on the instructions, I am supposed to download the files using the following instructions:

```
mkdir signin_helpers/ && cd signin_helpers
wget https://<project>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
wget https://<project>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler.js
wget https://<project>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/experiments.js
wget https://<project>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/iframe
wget https://<project>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/iframe.js
wget https://<project>.firebaseapp.com/__/firebase/init.json
```

While all other files (like `auth/handler` etc.) are getting downloaded successfully, I am not able to download `firebase/init.json` file. I am always getting a 404 error back on this particular file.

How can I download this particular file? Or is there an issue with the instructions provided? Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.